# How to I stun the Egyptian Zomboss?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

Sometimes, when battling Dr. Zomboss in the Egyptian fight, I manage to do something that put him in a stun animation. What is the trigger for that, or is it purely random?

Answer (score 2):

There is a distinct animation he uses indicating he's about to charge, taking out two rows of plants. If he takes a certain number of hits during this time, he will be stunned.

The most effective way to stun him is by using a plant food on a bonk choy at just the right moment.

Answer (score 0):

You might have not noticed that every time he loses on third of his health he gets stunned.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned above, you have to hit him for enough damage during his charge. I particularly liked firing the coconut cannon in his face to stun him.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 This answer suggests a different plant than the other answer. Therefore, it's not a dupe.